# creating/deleting gen folder

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I've downloaded a sample project. When I imported it to Eclipse I see an error in the BuildConfig.java class :

like :

[image]

The error indicates that i must delete dot (".").
but when I delete dot(".") - And then save it, error is corrected on the BuildConfig.java class.

now The error appears in the gen folder.

[image]

why ?

I deleted the gen folder, but again the same error is made.
[newest clips](http://www.newclip2ni.com/clip2ni-archives/kolah-ghermezi)

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're missing your own project's package name, or may be you have a misconfigured library.

Make up a unique package name (for instance, something like com.emamian.app, do not use com.example.app)

Also, right-click your project, click on 'Build config path...' (or something like that, click on Android in the left pane, then on the right side pane, scroll down and resolve any library problem by removing the libraries with red marks in front and re-adding them yourself manually by pressing the add button)

Then clean your project, look at the problems view, double-click on each problem (it will take you to the exact file and line where there is a problem), correct the missing package name at each location it tells you to.

Then Clean the project again and repeat the process until it works.

Comment: it is a simple project. my project : http://ubuntuone.com/0hmFFyea4dU3Bq3DrNRTMp :(

Comment: On the third line of your Android manifest file (in the root of your project folder, not in the gen/ folder). Replace .tayebi.sara.p2 with tayebi.sara.p2 (basically remove the '.' and save the file). Then do Project > Clean... (if you wait one minute, the red mark should clear up by itself once Eclipse has finished rebuilding the project)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot modify it manually. Clean the project or before importing, delete all other folders except src, res and the manifest. Always worked for me.

Comment: i deleted the gen folder, but again the same error is made.

Comment: it is a simple project. my project : it is a simple project. my project : http://ubuntuone.com/0hmFFyea4dU3Bq3DrNRTMp :(